# A) How many license plates are possible in Massachusetts, if the format must be 0-9, A-Z, A-Z ,0-9, 0-9, 0-9?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A) How many license plates are possible in Massachusetts, if the format must be 0-9, A-Z, A-Z ,0-9, 0-9, 0-9?
B) How many are possible if the format is the same, but the last three cannot all be the same number?

For part A, I have $26^2*10^4= 6,760,000$ because for 0-9 there are 10 options and for A-Z there are 26 options.

For part B, since the last three cannot all be the same, I have 0-9, A-Z, A-Z, but I'm not sure how to get the last three. Would it be $\frac{n_i}{10}$?

Comment: Calculate the number of plates with the same number, and subtract it from A.

Answer (score 3):

The number of plate codes with last three digits the same is $10×26×26×10$ where the last factor represents the digit that gets repeated. So the answer for (b) is $10×26^2×999$.

(Of course, the rules for licence plates are more complicated in real life...)

Comment: Why is it 999? $10^2-1$?

Comment: @Wng427 $10^3-1$, yes.

Comment: Okay, yes thank you!